# php How to Open Save As Dialog? Script Downloads Automatically

Tags: javascript, php, download, html2canvas

I have a download button that fires htmlcanvas and downloads html and saves it as a png file. I did not configure it as I don't understand javascript. I have played around with several tutorials for downloading files but I cannot get a dialog to open on click, regardless of which tutorial I have tried the image downloads to the download folder of whatever device the page is being viewed on. I think this is an issue with the javascript and not the php?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $loading = $('#loader').hide();
$('#carddownload').on('click', function() {
showimage(); 
});
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
$loading.show();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
$loading.hide();
});
function showimage(){
html2canvas([document.getElementById('card')], {
onrendered: function(canvas)
{
var img = canvas.toDataURL()
$.post("save.php", {data: img}, function (file) {
window.location.href ="downloadpng.php?path="+ file}); 
}
});
}
</script>

<?php
$file = trim($_GET['path']);
// force user to download the image
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "error not found";
}

?>
```

Comment: If you mean the "select where to save" dialog. That is a feature of the browser and the user configured settings, not something you can change. (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Doh! That was a waste of an hour! In chrome & firefox it saves automatically and in IE a window opens so if a user has not changed their settings by default will they see the where to save dialog regardless of the browser they're using?